# Verify identity $\sin 2x - \cot x = -\cot x \cos 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

Verify the identity:

$\sin 2x - \cot x = - \cot x \cos 2x$

I haven't gotten very far:

$2 \sin x \cos x - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ ...

Comment: Use the double angle formula.

Comment: I did on the left side.  Should I do it on the right side?  If yes, which one do I change the cos 2x to?

Comment: When $\cot x=0$ we have $0=0$. When $\cot x$ exists and is not $0$ then divide by $\cot x$, equivalently, multiply by $\tan X, $ giving $\sin 2x \tan x -1$ on the LHS and $-\cos 2x$ on the RHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you went backwards (which turns out to be easier),

$$\begin{align}-\cot x\cos 2x&=-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}(1-2\sin^2x)\\
&=-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} + 2\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\cdot\sin^2x\\
&= -\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} + 2\cos x\sin x\\
&= -\cot x + \sin2x\end{align}$$

If you went forward,

$$\begin{align}\sin2x - \cot x &= 2\sin x \cos x - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\\
&= \cos x\left(2\sin x - \frac{1}{\sin x}\right)\end{align}$$
Combining the expression in the bracket using the algebraic identity $a - \frac{1}{b} = \frac{ab - 1}{b}$, this simplifies to:
$$\cos x\left(\frac{2\sin^2x - 1}{\sin x}\right)$$
Using the double angle formula for $\cos$, $\cos2x = 1 - 2\sin^2x$, this becomes
$$\cos x \left(\frac{-\cos 2x}{\sin x}\right)\\
= \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}(-\cos 2x)\\
= -\cot x\cos2x$$

Comment: Thank you!  I am just trying to understand how you got from the second to last step to the last step, doing it forward..

Comment: @KKendall $\cos x (\frac{-\cos 2x}{\sin x}) = (\frac{\cos x}{\sin x})(-\cos 2x) = -\cot x \cos 2x$

Comment: I've made it more explicit, hope you can see it now!

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  I'm just trying to get this down better…  How did you get from (1−2sin2x) to 2sinxcosx?

Comment: Fixed again. It seems that I am skipping too many steps recently. Hope it now helps!

Comment: No worries, I'm just really bad at this.  Thanks for the help after I've already accepted it!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Double-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) ,

$$\cot x-\cot x\cos2x=\cot x(1-\cos2x)=\cot x\cdot2\sin^2x=2\sin x\cos x$$

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you can use the universal formulas !

$\tan2x-\frac{\cot x}{\cos2x}=-\cot x \implies \frac{1}{\tan x}(\frac{1}{\cos2x}-1)={\tan2x}\implies\frac{1}{\cos2x}=\frac{1+\tan^2x}{1-\tan^2x}$

Answer (score 0):

If $2x/\pi \not \in \mathbb Z$ then $\cot x$ exists and is not $0$ and we have  $$\sin 2x -\cot x=-\cos 2x \cot x $$ $$\iff (\sin 2x)( 1/\cot x)-1=-\cos 2x  $$ $$ \iff  (2\sin x \cos x)(\sin x\
/\cos x)-1 =-\cos 2x$$  $$\iff 2\sin^2 x-1=-\cos 2x$$ $$ \iff 2\sin^2 x=1-\cos 2x.$$ The last line above is a commonly-seen form of one of the angle-sum formulae, obtained from $\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1=2(1-\sin^2x)-1=1-2\sin^2 x.$

If $2x/\pi$ is an odd integer then $\cot x=0=\sin 2x, $ and the LHS and RHS are both $0$.

When $2x/\pi$ is an even integer  then $\cot x$ does not exist and neither the RHS nor the LHS have any meaning.